# Laravel 8+ и postman

Tags: laravel, openserver

Вообщем всё очень просто скачал последний laravel он вроде как 8.75 написал парочку моделей, миграций запустил всё это дело, и поскольку это всё таки апи кидаю запрос через postman для теста, а он просто 1000 лет выполняет запрос. В консоли видно, что laravel сервер запрос поймал, но не отвечает. БД крутится на openserver. Вообщем из-за чего может быть проблема?? Да кстати на зпросы из vuejs, абсолютно точно также.

Comment: Боюсь, что Ваш вопрос - кандидат на закрытие - проблему то воспроизвести невозможно... у и "100 лет" - это очень субъективно. Лучше бы в секундах... К тому же, хорошо бы разделить на "торможение фреймворка" и "торможение базы". А для этого надо "поймать", в какой SQL преобразовался запрос

Comment: ... и еще - я на знаю, у Ларавеля встроенные rate limiter'ы есть на api? может, в эту сторону посмотреть?

Comment: @S.H. "100 лет" - это очень субъективно. Лучше бы в секундах... К сожалению в секундах не могу, потомучто ответа нету, т.е. фактически запрос не кончается. Уже почти 15 минут идёт, и всё никак не кончается. БД обычная mysql 8.0.

Судя по докам у ларавеля есть rate limiter

Comment: @S.H. Я просто к тому, что может у кого-нибуть такая же есть проблема.